# Docker - Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /app/Uploads/Images/

Tags: c#, docker, file, docker-compose, devops

I want to dockerize my api, I have problem with folder Uploads/Images, I haven't saved images direct in database, I have saved it in api in folder Uploads/Images and only what I do is to get path from database and on that way I read that image. When I run command "docker run -p 5192:5192 --name eres-api-container eres-api", I will get next exception, how can I fix this?

```
docker run -p 5192:5192 --name eres-api-container eres-api
Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /app/Uploads/Images/
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /src/e-Res/Program.cs:line 124
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5192
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5192


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "e-Res/e-Res.csproj" -c Release -o /app
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "e-Res.dll"]
```

EDIT - WORKS
COPY ./e-Res/Uploads/Images ./Uploads/Images

Comment: Probably, the folder is not created, add WORKDIR /app/Uploads/Images or mkdir /app/Uploads/Images in you Dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to add the `<Content>` tag to the .csproj file as below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        ...
        <Content Include="photos\*">
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```